# Photo's metadata and converting to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, alassetslibrary

So my app lets a user select a photo from the iOS device's Photo Library. When selected, I check for GPS Metadata:

```
NSString *mediatType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediatType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

    if (url) {
        ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetsLibrary assetForURL:url
                       resultBlock:^(ALAsset *myasset) {
                           CLLocation *photoLocation = [myasset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
                           DLog(@"photoLocation: %@", photoLocation);
                       }
                      failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                          DLog(@"can't get image: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                      }];
    }
}
```

I'm a bit lost now at this point, I need to convert the Photo to NSData for local storage and then to Base64 to upload to our server.

If I use:

```
NSData *photoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 1);
```

Will that wrap up the metadata into the image file/data so when I upload, the server will be able to read the metadata in the image file?

Comment: Never use `1` for the compression level of a JPEG image. That gives stupidly large image files. Use something like `0.8` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImage meta data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582829/uiimage-meta-data)