# Adding or overwriting GPS metadata without losing any other data and save with PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, metadata, phphotolibrary

Currently I'm changing over from **ALAssetsLibrary** to **PHPhotoLibrary**.

I want to add or overwrite GPS metadata on JPEG file **without** losing any other data.

With ALAssetsLibrary, we could do it like below

```
- (void)saveImageDataToPhotoAlbum:(NSData *)originalData
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *dataDic = [self getMetaDataWithGps:originalData];

    [assetsLib writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:originalData
                                       metadata:[self getMetadataWithGpsInfo:originalData]
                                completionBlock:^(NSURL *url, NSError *e) {
                                    [self addToMyAlbum:url];
                                }];
}

- (NSDictionary *)getMetadataWithGpsInfo:(NSData *)originalData
{
    CGImageSourceRef cimage = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)data, nil);
    NSDictionary *metadata = (NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(cimage, 0, nil);
    NSMutableDictionary *metadataAsMutable = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:metadata];

    metadataAsMutable[(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary] = self.myGpsDic;

    [metadata release];  
    CFRelease(cimage);

    return metadataAsMutable;
}
```

But with **PHPhotoLibrary** I cannot do the same thing.

I tried to create NSData(made from JPEG file) with adding or overwriting GPS metadata.
I **could** create and save image data with GPS metadata.
But it lost thumbnail data and other data(such as maker note). Moreover the file size([data length]) reduced from about 5MB to about 3MB.

My code to create image data with GPS metadata is like below,

```
- (NSData *)getDataWithGpsInfo:(NSData *)originalData
{
    CGImageSourceRef cimage = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)data, nil);
    NSDictionary *metadata = (NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(cimage, 0, nil);
    NSMutableDictionary *metadataAsMutable = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:metadata];

    metadataAsMutable[(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary] = self.myGpsDic;

    NSMutableData *dataWithLocationInfo = [NSMutableData data];
    CGImageDestinationRef dest =
        CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef)dataWithLocationInfo, CGImageSourceGetType(cimage), 1, nil);
    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(dest, cimage, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)metadataAsMutable);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest);
    CFRelease(dest);

    [metadata release];  
    CFRelease(cimage);

    return dataWithLocationInfo;
}
```

In case of **ALAssetsLibraray**, the file size before/after adding GPS metadata is almost same (5MB).

I looked for and tried several ways like the following questions but they cannot resolve this issue.

- [Save the exif metadata using the new PHPhotoLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758510/save-the-exif-metadata-using-the-new-phphotolibrary)
- [UIImage meta data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582829/uiimage-meta-data)
- [Writing a Photo with Metadata using Photokit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102037/writing-a-photo-with-metadata-using-photokit)

If you have any good idea, please let me know. I'd appreciate any information about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question to Apple with TSI(Technical Support Incident).
But they didn't give clear answer to resolve the issue.

Now I decide to use ALAssetsLibrary's API when saving image with adding location info.

```
- (void)writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSData *)imageData metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
```